# Pointing NLB to classic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-nlb, aws-private-link

I have a Classic Load Balancer for my kubernetes, but now I want to use AWS PrivateLink so I need to make use of a Network Load Balancer.

Is there any way to point the Network Load Balancer to the Classic Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

You could only do it by using private IP addresses of your Classic Load Balancer. The addresses are not static, so such setup won't last long. It would be better to just use Network Load Balancer directly with your kubernetes.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: @DevOps Specifically for what? The CLB?